# Java calling pre-parent method of child class

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, encapsulation

In c++ you can easely call eny oveloaded method from any previus parent classes.
How an i do somethink like that in Java?

Example:

```java
class A {

    public void f() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }

};

class B extends A {

    @Override
    public void f() {  
        super.f();
        System.out.println("B");
    }

};

class C extends B {

    @Override
    public void f() {  
        super.f(); // how to invoke f() method of A class avoiding B class?
        System.out.println("C");
    }

};
```

So calling c.f() will print "ABC".

How to call from C class method of A class avoiding same overloaded method of B class?

Comment: You can't do that in Java.

Comment: Well it's very sad than.

Comment: IMHO It is very sad that C++ will let you mess with the hierarchy this way.

Comment: @CookieMonster Yes. Very Sad.

Comment: It's very useful actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have already pointed out, you can't get it directly (For example `super.super.` doesn't work).

Here is a *hack* you can mess around with:

```
try
{
    Class<?> s = this.getClass();
    while ( !"java.lang.Object".equals(s.getSuperclass().getName())  )
    {
        s = s.getSuperclass();
    }
    Method m = s.getMethod(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName(), (Class<?>[])null);
    if ( m != null )
    {
        m.invoke(s.newInstance()); // This is the actual call to the 'super' method.
    }
}
catch ( Exception e )
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It's not pretty, but for simple classes and methods it works ;)

ps. This hack only supports methods without any parameters. If you need to support parameters you'll need to use the `getMethods()` method. Also, if the final "superclass" doesn't support the method it'll also not work, but you can add code in the while loop to check that and catch the last superclass that does support it.

Answer (score 7):

In Java you can't do this without a hack because C is a B not just an A.  If you can do this in C++, it's a bad idea IMHO. This suggests your hierarchy is messed up and C should be only an A not a B.

If you really have to do this you can add a method to B like this so you can bypass B.f();

```
protected void superF() {
    super.f();
}
```

and call this from C.

---

It is possible to generate the byte code using ASM to do this.  The byte code allows you to call any level of parent, it is Java which does not.

Comment: I have source only of C class.

Comment: @CookieMonster You can decompile B and "fix" it. Also you can make C a subclass of A.

Comment: Well i can get source from GrepCode. But if i'll do that then i'll have to get all other sources that are being used there.

Comment: @CookieMonster You only need the source of one class which you can compile using the compiled classes you already have.  If it doesn't compile you have the wrong version.

Comment: What happens if you say `super.super.F()` in C?

Comment: @Ingo it doesn't compile.

Comment: @Peter no, "in class C"

Comment: @PeterLawrey This is then indeed completly illogical, and lacks orthogonality. The more so as it is finally possible with the trick you give.

Answer (score 0):

No this can't be done in java. However if you want it to be done create an instance of class A in overridden method f() of class C and invoke f() of class A using the object.